# C++ linker error when linking two object files from differen projects containing the same symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, dependencies, c++-cx

I have two projects(ProjA and ProjB). In ProjA I create TypeA.obj which contains definition of TypeA. ProjB depends on ProjA. In Sth.obj from ProjB I use TypeA.

The Problem appears at linker phase of ProjC, which links TypeA.obj and Sth.obj. I get error saying that TypeA is already defined in Sth.obj.

Is it possible in c++ to link multiple obj files each of which contain the same symbol(in this case TypeA symbol)?

EDIT!

Ok, now I will go into more detail. First of all when I started this thread I described my problem as related to c++,
even though I have problems with c++/cx. I thought that this is generic problem for c++ and c++/cx. After some analysis
I don't think so anymore. Forgive me for this mistake.

Most propably my problem is related to c++/cx only.

Below I present you with more detailed description of my solution in visual studio

```
ProjA
    #####MyType.h#####
    #pragma once
    namespace N1
    {
    public ref class MyType sealed
    {
    };
    }

    #####MyType.cpp#####
    #include "pch.h"
    #include "MyType.h"

ProjB
    #####MyTypeUser.h#####
    namespace N2
    {
    [Windows::Foundation::Metadata::WebHostHidden]
    public ref class MyTypeUser sealed
    {
    public:
        void DoSth(N1::MyType){}
    }
    }

    #####MyTypeUser.cpp#####
    #include "pch.h"
    #include "MyTypeUser.h"

ProjC
    links MyType.obj and MyTypeUser.obj
```

At linker phase of ProjC I get error that MyType have been already defined in MyType.obj or in MyTypeUser(depend which is linked first).

Comment: An attempted (and failed) [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) would probably be considerably more informative. Apart from that, this *sounds* like you should be using a dynamic code module (a DLL in Windows, a .so in Linux, for example) for *implementing* TypeA.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create namespaces for these projects, and use these namespaces to identify the individual objects. Same as we use std namespace.

```
std::cout << "Hello World!" <<std::endl;
```

Comment: Both obj files that ProjC links, contain exact the same type TypeA. It is not a problem of linking 2 different types sharing the same name.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to have one class definition appear several times, even if they are identical. You will need to setup your projects in a different way. It is possible to wrap the same class into different namespaces to avoid the clash, but this kind of thing leads to very painful maintenance problems later on. Better to solve it now.

Why not create another project, independent from the rest, that contains just the class (or other type definition) you need in several places?

You might want to add another tag to your question (e.g. Visual C++?) to get more specific help on how to refactor the projects, depending on your IDE.